# AKS HPA setting configurable properties

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod, hpa

We are using AKS 1.19.11 version and would like to know whether we could enable the configurable scaling behavior in AKS also as [Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/).

If yes, the current hpa setting used is with `apiversion: autoscaling/v1`. Is it possible to configure these hpa behavior properties with these api version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask specifically about `behavior` field, the answer is: **no, it's not available in `apiVersion: autoscaling/v1`** and if you want to leverage it, you need to use `autoscaling/v2beta2`. It's clearly stated [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-configurable-scaling-behavior):

> Starting from v1.18 the v2beta2 API allows scaling behavior to be
> configured through the HPA behavior field.

If you have doubts, you can easily check it on your own by trying to apply a new `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` object definition, containing this field, but instead of required `autoscaling/v2beta2`, use `autoscaling/v1`. You should see the error message similar to the one below:

```
error: error validating "nginx-multiple.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(HorizontalPodAutoscaler.spec): unknown field "behavior" in io.k8s.api.autoscaling.v1.HorizontalPodAutoscalerSpec, ValidationError(HorizontalPodAutoscaler.spec): unknown field "metrics" in io.k8s.api.autoscaling.v1.HorizontalPodAutoscalerSpec]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

As you can see both `metrics` and `behavior` fields in `spec` are not valid in `autoscaling/v1` however they are perfectly valid in `autoscaling/v2beta2` API.

To check whether your **AKS** cluster supports this API version, run:

```
$ kubectl api-versions | grep autoscaling
autoscaling/v1
autoscaling/v2beta1
autoscaling/v2beta2
```

If your result is similar to mine (i.e. you can see `autoscaling/v2beta2`), it means your **AKS** cluster supports this API version.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can use it.

### Example of Build in HPA file:

```yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  labels:
    app: prediction-api
  name: prediction-api
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: prediction-api
  maxReplicas: 4
  minReplicas: 1
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 70
```

---

#### Custom scaling metrics

- You can use the [Keda](https://keda.sh/) - https://keda.sh/ project for custom Event-driven Autoscaling.

[image]

Comment: my question was about whether its possible to set the hpa additional propery like behavior ( scale up and scale down ) properties in AKS the same way Kubernetes.io syays.